# root partition disk is full, how to clear it?

Tags: 15.04, disk-usage

I have a brand new System76 laptop w/15.04, 250G SSD as root partition.
I was playing around with pycharm, doing a tutorial when i get a pop-up saying no disk space remaining.
I close out of pycharm and open file manager, sure enough, my ssd is full.
I've rebooted, but still have my root part full.

How do i find out whats filling it up and clear it out??

UPDATE: I used a 'du -k / | sort -n' to find the largest files being used on the disk, then deleted them.

Comment: You can remove: 1) Older or unused kernels (they use quite a few space); 2) Unused programs; 3) You could clear your home folder; 4) Always use Ctrl+H in your file manager to show hidden directories/folders.

Comment: this is a brand new machine, no older kernels, very few programs installed, home folder is practically empty...

Comment: Try opening GParted, take a screenshot and post it here.

Comment: don't have gparted installed, and cant install it.  (tried apt-get install gparted, got: "The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened"

Comment: Did you use this partition before installing Ubuntu?

Comment: I didn't do the install, System76 did.

Comment: But anyway, did you use the partition before Ubuntu?

Comment: It came to me with ubuntu installed, so, no, i never used it before ubuntu...

FYI- i cant post a screenshot because i have no reputation....

Comment: Do you have an Ubuntu Live CD?

Comment: THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE. There is a problem with Ubuntu 15.04 filling up the /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ directory. This has struck others as well. I will post the answer if the question is reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **baobab**, a disk usage analyzer. It is installed by default

It will help you troubleshoot your problem.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Baobab

Comment: My God, Magnum.    I needed this name to be able to use it with sudo.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

try `sudo apt-get autoclean` to remove the apt cache. It will give you some more space.

Comment: it freed 1.5GB in my machine!